# How can I get the x and y coordinates from UnsafeMutableBufferPointer

Tags: swift

I am getting all the pixels of an image with the following:

```
let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt32>.allocate(capacity: size)
```

Later I iterate through all pixels and get the RGB color:

```
for pixel in buffer {
    var r : UInt32 = 0
    var g : UInt32 = 0
    var b : UInt32 = 0
    if cgImage.byteOrderInfo == .orderDefault || cgImage.byteOrderInfo == .order32Big {
        r = pixel & 255
        g = (pixel >> 8) & 255
        b = (pixel >> 16) & 255
    } else if cgImage.byteOrderInfo == .order32Little {
        r = (pixel >> 16) & 255
        g = (pixel >> 8) & 255
        b = pixel & 255
    }
}
```

Currently, I can get the color but I would in addition like to get the x and y coordinate of that pixel.  Would anyone have a way to implement this?

The only way I can think of is iterate through each pixel by x and y and then get each point's byte and get the color but I was thinking UnsafeMutableBufferPointer is faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image has a `width` and `height` where `size = width * height`.

Add `.enumerated()` to `buffer` in your `for` loop to get the `index` of the pixel.  Divide and mod by the `width` to find the `(x, y)` coordinates of the pixel:

```
for (index, pixel) in buffer.enumerated() {
    let x = index % width
    let y = index / width

    var r : UInt32 = 0
    var g : UInt32 = 0
    var b : UInt32 = 0
    if cgImage.byteOrderInfo == .orderDefault || cgImage.byteOrderInfo == .order32Big {
        r = pixel & 255
        g = (pixel >> 8) & 255
        b = (pixel >> 16) & 255
    } else if cgImage.byteOrderInfo == .order32Little {
        r = (pixel >> 16) & 255
        g = (pixel >> 8) & 255
        b = pixel & 255
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Why didn't I think of that. Thanks